# States not getting stored in database using city-state gem in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, drop-down-menu, rubygems

so I am using a gem called city-state gem in my web application to populate a dropdown list with the 50 states of US, but I am unable to save the selected value in the database,maybe I am missing something here, I have the following code:

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, :class=>'well form-horizontal' ,:style=>"margin-top:30px",url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <select name="form[state]">
    <% CS.states(:us).each do |key, value| %>
      <option value="<%= key %>"><%= value %></option>
    <% end %>
  </select>
<% end %>
```

I tried using

```
<%= f.select :state, value %>
```

but that would give me an empty dropdown list, any help appreciated.Thanks in advance.

```
Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓","authenticity_token"=>"w1dXvna7zYZ96f9pNtCdm3ruIHu/J9+kXZ6rxoPy+7QJCqTDAs+Y1ZcOgUvRiJEEZpyJ3S0qpLEbfoKEr+15bw==", "user"=>{"firstname"=>"Han", "lastname"=>"Park", "gender"=>"Male", "dob(1i)"=>"1996", "dob(2i)"=>"12", "dob(3i)"=>"6", "ssn"=>"1432229824", "driver_license"=>"D768765764", "street_address"=>"1000 north", "city"=>"New York", "zip"=>"60098", "email"=>"han@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "tandc"=>"true"}, "state"=>"MD", "commit"=>"Sign Up"}
DEPRECATION WARNING: ssn is not an attribute known to Active Record. This 
behavior is deprecated and will be removed in the next version of Rails. If 
you'd like ssn to be managed by Active Record, add `attribute :ssn to your 
class. (called from block in attr_encrypted at /Users/reynold/.rvm/gems/ruby-
2.2.2/gems/attr_encrypted-
3.0.3/lib/attr_encrypted/adapters/active_record.rb:75)
(0.3ms)  BEGIN 
User Exists (0.8ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1 
LIMIT $2  [["email", "han@saveup.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
SQL (6.2ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("email", "encrypted_password", "created_at", 
"updated_at", "firstname", "lastname", "gender", "encrypted_ssn", 
"encrypted_ssn_iv", "street_address", "city", "zip", "driver_license", 
"tandc", "dob") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12, 
$13, $14, $15) RETURNING "id"  [["email", "han@saveup.com"], 
["encrypted_password", 
"$2a$11$asC6.rG.aYUXJa8Ps.Gbeu3FzTFw64urmIB2KK9rxj94sH71gXaYm"], 
["created_at", "2017-12-06 22:17:55.383121"], ["updated_at", "2017-12-06 
22:17:55.383121"], ["firstname", "Han"], ["lastname", "Park"], ["gender", 
"Male"], ["encrypted_ssn", "eWjL/lDpivR3T9cXx1w6rg==\n"], ["encrypted_ssn_iv", 
"Rt/5Tl6PkwvqOjDC9nN1ng==\n"], ["street_address", "1000 north"], ["city", 
"New York"], ["zip", "60098"], ["driver_license", "D768765764"], ["tandc", 
"t"], ["dob", "1996-12-06"]]
(0.6ms)  COMMIT
(0.3ms)  BEGIN
SQL (2.4ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "sign_in_count" = $1, "current_sign_in_at" = 
$2, "last_sign_in_at" = $3, "current_sign_in_ip" = $4, "last_sign_in_ip" = $5, 
"updated_at" = $6 WHERE "users"."id" = $7  [["sign_in_count", 1], 
["current_sign_in_at", "2017-12-06 22:17:55.397080"], ["last_sign_in_at", 
"2017-12-06 22:17:55.397080"], ["current_sign_in_ip", "127.0.0.1/32"], 
["last_sign_in_ip", "127.0.0.1/32"], ["updated_at", "2017-12-06 
22:17:55.398231"], ["id", 18]]
(0.5ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 276ms (ActiveRecord: 11.1ms)


Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-12-06 16:17:55 -0600
User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 
ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 18], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Processing by HomeController#roothome as HTML
Rendering home/roothome.html.erb within layouts/application
Rendered shared/_comparechart.html.erb (1.0ms)
Rendered shared/_disclaimer.html.erb (0.7ms)
Rendered home/roothome.html.erb within layouts/application (8.1ms)
Rendered _navbar.html.erb (4.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 478ms (Views: 474.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Comment: Is the select rendered correctly? If you're having problems saving to the database (and not rendering the select), then you should show us, minimally, your console output and the code where you expect the data to be saved. Otherwise, there's nothing we can do to help you.

Comment: @jvillian ,I am just going through the example provided by the city-state gem ,here is the link: https://www.learnwithdaniel.com/2015/02/citystate-list-of-countries-cities-and-states-ruby/   , I have also put up the logs, please do take a look. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of building out the form tag and options manually wouldn’t it be cleaner to let rails do it? This would also have fixed the name issue for you:

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, :class=>'well form-horizontal' ,:style=>"margin-top:30px",url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= f.select :state, CS.states(:us) %>
<% end %>
```

Rails will also handle populating the current value when editing for you this way.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing (since you didn't show us your controller code) that you expect `state` to be a part of the `user` params. But, as you can see, it is not:

```
{
  "utf8"=>"✓",
  "authenticity_token"=>"w1dXvna7zYZ96f9pNtCdm3ruIHu/J9+kXZ6rxoPy+7QJCqTDAs+Y1ZcOgUvRiJEEZpyJ3S0qpLEbfoKEr+15bw==", 
  "user"=>{
    "firstname"=>"Han", 
    "lastname"=>"Park", 
    "gender"=>"Male", 
    "dob(1i)"=>"1996", 
    "dob(2i)"=>"12", 
    "dob(3i)"=>"6", 
    "ssn"=>"1432229824", 
    "driver_license"=>"D768765764", 
    "street_address"=>"1000 north", 
    "city"=>"New York", 
    "zip"=>"60098", 
    "email"=>"han@gmail.com", 
    "password"=>"[FILTERED]", 
    "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", 
    "tandc"=>"true"
  }, 
  "state"=>"MD", 
  "commit"=>"Sign Up"
}
```

I *think* it's because you do:

```
<select name="form[state]">
```

You probably want something like:

```
<select name="user[state]">
```

I'm not sure about that syntax, so you'll have to monkey with it.

Comment: Damn your absolutely correct, it worked... Thanks mate :-D